# Laravel returning email not verified even it is verified

Tags: laravel, api, email, breeze

I have this screenshots of my problem.
So basically I'm new to Laravel and I'm using api to interact.
I have this breeze setup, and got my first user register and verified email.
However, when accessing a protected route, it is still saying email not verified.
Here is my messed up codes in laravel
https://github.com/isaacnewtonaranas/api24

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you cache user data? If you cached, you must flush the cache first. And also you can set flush cache in booted method on user's model

Comment: I'm not caching users. I hope it's not caching users cause I only use boiler plate breeze, so settings must have things like that or not. I tried search for flush cache and found this php artisan optimize:clear and tried, but still showing that email is not verified.